# Extremly low accuracy in "Deep MNIST for Experts" using Pascal GPU

Tags: tensorflow

first of all, I'm abit unsure if I should have asked this on Github or here, but since I wasn't sure I opted to go with stackoverflow.

I recently got a Nvidia GTX 1070 and wanted to try out tensorflow with it. I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, the nvidia-367 driver from the "Graphics Drivers Team" PPA, nvidia-cuda-toolkit 7.5.18-0ubuntu1 and cuDNN v4 (Feb 10, 2016).

Tensorflow was installed according to https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html follwing the "Virtualenv installation", using this TF_BINARY_URL:

```
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 2.7 
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v4. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
(tensorflow)$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

The first tutorial seems to work fine, and I've run a few other example models that also seem to work fine, but for some reason I'm getting an accuracy of about 9.5% in the "Deep MNIST for Experts" tutorial.

At first I thought I had made some error copy-pasting the code and spent some time trying to debug it to no avail. Then I found this issue on github https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2781 and tried downloading his code and dont get anywhere close to 90% accuracy. I also tried fixing the bug in the code, so the train step runs every iteration, with no luck.

This is the output I get from running the tut.py from the above mentioned issue on github, modified to run train_step on each iteration of the loop:

```
$ python -i tut.py
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
>>> conv_net()
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:924] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:102] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1070
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7715
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 7.46GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:806] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
step 0, training accuracy 0.14
step 100, training accuracy 0.1
step 200, training accuracy 0.16
step 300, training accuracy 0.12
step 400, training accuracy 0.1
step 500, training accuracy 0.08

   [....]

step 19500, training accuracy 0.18
step 19600, training accuracy 0.06
step 19700, training accuracy 0.1
step 19800, training accuracy 0.12
step 19900, training accuracy 0.08
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:213] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 5.84GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.
test accuracy 0.0954
```

I might also add that I'm fairly sure I ran this tutorial a while back using an older GPU, and didn't have any issues, so somehow I get the feeling that something with the Pascal architecture isn't supported properly. What's even stranger is that some of the more complex models like the CNN and RNN "tutorials"/examples (seems to) run fine.

Edit:

I installed the CPU version using

```
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 2.7
(tensorflow)$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

and running 1000 iterations (instead of 20000) gives this result:

```
$ python -i tut.py 
>>> conv_net()
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
step 0, training accuracy 0.14
step 100, training accuracy 0.88
step 200, training accuracy 0.88
step 300, training accuracy 0.82
step 400, training accuracy 0.94
step 500, training accuracy 0.92
step 600, training accuracy 0.98
step 700, training accuracy 0.94
step 800, training accuracy 0.9
step 900, training accuracy 1
test accuracy 0.9648
```

Guess I'll try making a reinstall from source with newer versions for "everything".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing newer versions of CUDA and CuDNN seems to have solved the issue. (I saw the download page for CuDNN explicitly states that version 4 doesn't work with GTX 1070/1080.)

What worked for me was:

- use the "Graphics Drivers Team" Ubuntu PPA thingy for installing the nvidia-367 drivers.
- install CUDA 8.0RC using the runfile, didn't install the bundled driver. I tried the deb file but there were  some  issues with it wanting to install the bundled nvidia-361 driver. I never tried the third option (some tar.gz file IIRC?)
- installed bazel from source, again I had some issues with the custom apt repo due to some dependency on java.
- I used HEAD from tensorflows git repo, no particular reason.
- I ran into [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/817) (or something very similar). This was solved by switching to gcc-4.9 instead of the default. (I only changed the path in the configure script for tensorflow.) I have no idea why this works, and it was something of a lucky guess.
- Think I needed to install the zlib1g-dev package due to missing header files, but if so the error message was very clear that this was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my mistake...(I deleted previous answer.)
but I've found the solution.
check the following link.
you have to join developer of nvidia. and download cuda-8.0 (after installing cuda-8.0, it is necessary to reinstall nvidia driver!)

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-release-candidate-download